# How to use HTTP GET on VS Code to connect to Spotify API

Tags: javascript, http, get, spotify

I am trying to connect to Spotify's API in JavaScript on VS Code. I already made a developer account and created a new app, and I have used Spotify's sample authorization_code app.js offered on their github to get authorization and receive my tokens. I need to use my tokens to demo connecting to Spotify's API and receiving a raw data output. From here, I am stuck because I am not sure how to do that, as I am still new to learning JavaScript and API's. I am using Spotify's developer website to try to fetch data for "Get Artist", and it allows me to insert my ID and token to give me the HTTP GET methods to connect to the API. These are the get methods given for me to use:

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{id}

curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/<my id>" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>"
```

Spotify printed the sample output below, which is what I am trying to get as an output from the terminal on VS code:

```
{
"external_urls": {
    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg"
},
"followers": {
    "href": null,
    "total": 9580653
},
"genres": [
    "dance pop",
    "miami hip hop",
    "pop",
    "pop rap"
],
"href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg",
"id": "0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg",
"images": [
 {
     "height": 640,
     "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5eb2dc40ac263ef07c16a95af4e",
     "width": 640
 },
 {
     "height": 320,
     "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab676161000051742dc40ac263ef07c16a95af4e",
     "width": 320
 },
 {
     "height": 160,
      "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000f1782dc40ac263ef07c16a95af4e",
      "width": 160
 }
 ],
 "name": "Pitbull",
 "popularity": 82,
 "type": "artist",
 "uri": "spotify:artist:0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg"
```

}

This may sound dumb, but what am I supposed to write in VS Code to get this to work? In VS Code I have a folder "authorization_code" with the files that helped me receive my access tokens. I want to be able to run my code in the terminal, where the above output would be returned. What am I supposed to do with the HTTP commands given to me by Spotify in order to get that output? Do I need any other files to make this work? I'm sorry, I am still just learning how this language works and how to connect to everything. I just simply want to know how I use my tokens given to connect to the Get Artist API in VS Code and get the raw data.

This is the authorization_code I used to receive my tokens:

```
    /**
     * This is an example of a basic node.js script that performs
     * the Authorization Code oAuth2 flow to authenticate against
     * the Spotify Accounts.
     *
     * For more information, read
     * https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow
     */

    var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework
    var request = require('request'); // "Request" library
    var cors = require('cors');
    var querystring = require('querystring');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
 
    var client_id = '<removed for post>'; // Your client id
    var client_secret = '<removed for post>'; // Your secret
    var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback'; // Your redirect uri

    /**
     * Generates a random string containing numbers and letters
     * @param  {number} length The length of the string
     * @return {string} The generated string
     */
     var generateRandomString = function(length) {
         var text = '';
         var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
 
          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
              text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
          }
          return text;
    };
 
    var stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';
 
    var app = express();
 
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
    .use(cors())
    .use(cookieParser());
 
 app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
 
   var state = generateRandomString(16);
   res.cookie(stateKey, state);
 
   // your application requests authorization
   var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
   res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
     querystring.stringify({
       response_type: 'code',
       client_id: client_id,
       scope: scope,
       redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
       state: state
     }));
 });
 
 app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {
 
   // your application requests refresh and access tokens
   // after checking the state parameter

 /**
  * URL built up from running node app.js (CONTAINS ACCESS & REFRESH TOKENS!!!):
  * http://localhost:8888/#
  * access_token=BQCDky3kGL4j0emQNntiOZsaVBbI5ZkXAfukxmRrjWnAJJGPggVC1hQuEAYhi2nrqKHjt0uVo1MPfOcP_RMdVCCz40TcQArK9vKfxHJplhQRYnl0TZPLDQhYh90ocX3nvnMQzT1kJgUihXnIH-GJ2ZlJ9ol-mwCuh-ro1YrSGhVn2a65kZAYKF5bDjN5-VC2YM2VQAIJmGULsJ-_q77b9Q
  * &refresh_token=AQDiCPC2Rh0nA0fVg9tCcgY7yUnKz8Zm3G4fUXMVAN5FhIHJpGgFTcFSZ4DAr44ujDMDhygkHw0Us4JnDYJUEMkYIsQaxtgduipF3nDV2JEusZOGC38mssf_W_gzMvzZfNY
  */
 
   var code = req.query.code || null;
   var state = req.query.state || null;
   var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;
 
   if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
     res.redirect('/#' +
       querystring.stringify({
         error: 'state_mismatch'
       }));
   } else {
     res.clearCookie(stateKey);
     var authOptions = {
       url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
       form: {
         code: code,
         redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
         grant_type: 'authorization_code'
       },
       headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
       },
       json: true
     };
 
     request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
       if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
 
         var access_token = body.access_token,
             refresh_token = body.refresh_token;
 
         var options = {
           url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/31v737d3i7ldefyjefodkxrxalnu',
           headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
           json: true
         };
 
         // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
         request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
           console.log(body);
         });
 
         // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
         res.redirect('/#' +
           querystring.stringify({
             access_token: access_token,
             refresh_token: refresh_token
           }));
       } else {
         res.redirect('/#' +
           querystring.stringify({
             error: 'invalid_token'
           }));
       }
     });
   }
 });
 
 app.get('/refresh_token', function(req, res) {
 
   // requesting access token from refresh token
   var refresh_token = req.query.refresh_token;
   var authOptions = {
     url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
     headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')) },
     form: {
       grant_type: 'refresh_token',
       refresh_token: refresh_token
     },
     json: true
   };
 
   request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
     if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
       var access_token = body.access_token;
       res.send({
         'access_token': access_token
       });
     }
   });
 });


 console.log('Listening on 8888');
 app.listen(8888);
```

This is the code I tried to add so that I could fetch the Spotify Get Artist API raw data.  I just want to be able to get an output like the sample I included in my terminal when I execute.

```
request.open('GET', 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{id}', true);
request.onload = Function ()
{
   var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
   if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
     var access_token = body.access_token,
     refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

     var options = {
       url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/<my id>',
       headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
       json: true
     };

     // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
     request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
       console.log(body);
     });

     // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
     res.redirect('/#' + querystring.stringify({
       access_token: access_token,
       refresh_token: refresh_token
     }));
   } else {
     res.redirect('/#' + querystring.stringify({
       error: 'invalid_token'
     }));
   }
}

request.send();
```

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear. You mention vscode as if you would write an extension, but I guess you are just trying to use the API.  You managed to make an API call for the token, so what is stopping you now to make another request?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski  I'm honestly just frustrated and confused at this point because I feel like I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be. In my authorization_code, which I ran to receive my tokens through the browser, I tried to write a function to make a request to Get Artist which came up with an error, and I'm not sure how to make it work because I have limited experience with this language.  I edited this post to include my authorization code.